# Simple test with Scala Test 1.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm trying to run a test using Scala 2.8 in IntelliJ 10 with Scala Test 1.2

I don't know much scala syntax, so can you help with *this code* ? :)

```
package test.ui {

import org.scalatest._
import matchers.ShouldMatchers
import ui._
import observer._

object ButtonObserverSpecification extends Spec {
  "A Button Observer should observe button clicks" in {
      val observableButton = new ObservableButton("Okay")
      val buttonObserver = new ButtonCountObserver
      observableButton.addObserver(buttonObserver)

      for (i <- 1 to 3) observableButton.click()
      buttonObserver.count should equal (3)
    }
  }
}
```

**The error is :**

```
error: value in is not a member of java.lang.String
"A Button Observer should observe button clicks" in {
```

Here is the rest of the code :

```
package ui {

abstract class Widget

class Button(val label: String) extends Widget {
  def click() = {
    println (label + " was clicked")
  }
}

}

package observer {

trait Subject {
  type Observer = {def receiveUpdate(subject: Any)}
  private var observers = List[Observer]()

  def addObserver(observer: Observer) = observers ::= observer

  def notifyObservers = observers foreach (_.receiveUpdate(this))
}

}

package ui {

import observer._

class ObservableButton(name: String) extends Button(name) with Subject {
  override def click() = {
    super.click()
    notifyObservers
  }
}

class ButtonCountObserver {
  var count = 0

  def receiveUpdate(subject: Any) = count += 1
}

}
```

*The code is from the book "Programming Scala" from Oreilly*

I tried updating the code to Scala test 1.2, but failed. Here is the original test (notice the imports and the extended class):

```
package ui
import org.specs._
import observer._

object ButtonObserverSpec extends Specification {
  "A Button Observer" should {
    "observe button clicks" in {
      val observableButton = new ObservableButton("Okay")
      val buttonObserver = new ButtonCountObserver
      observableButton.addObserver(buttonObserver)

      for (i <- 1 to 3) observableButton.click()
      buttonObserver.count mustEqual 3
    }
  }
}
```

**Trial number 3** *(Error is No tests were found)* :

```
package test.ui {

import org.scalatest._
import matchers.ShouldMatchers
import ui._
import observer._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
object ButtonObserverTest extends WordSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  "A Button Observer" should {
    "observe button clicks" in {
      val observableButton = new ObservableButton("Okay")
      val buttonObserver = new ButtonCountObserver
      observableButton.addObserver(buttonObserver)

      for (i <- 1 to 3) observableButton.click()
      buttonObserver.count should equal (3)
    }
  }
}
}
```

**Working test :**

```
package test.ui {

import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import ui._
import observer._

class ButtonObserverTest extends WordSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  "A Button Observer" should {
    "observe button clicks" in {
      val observableButton = new ObservableButton("Okay")
      val buttonObserver = new ButtonCountObserver
      observableButton.addObserver(buttonObserver)

      for (i <- 1 to 3) observableButton.click()
      buttonObserver.count should equal (3)
    }
  }
}
}
```

*PS :* If you don't know how to run scala tests in IntelliJ, see [this blog post - IntelliJ Now Supports ScalaTest](http://jackcoughonsoftware.blogspot.com/2009/04/intellij-now-supports-scalatest.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to extend `WordSpec` with `ShouldMatchers` like this :

```
class ButtonObserverSpec extends WordSpec with ShouldMatchers {...}
```

You can find more examples here:

http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_bdd

Comment: @Belun - You can either add annotation `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` to test class (if you are using JUnit runner) or use IDEA's ScalaTest runner.

Comment: i am using the Idea ScalaTest... still no tests found

Comment: @Belun - do you have classnotfound exception?

Comment: no. it just says No tests were found. (i did remove @RunWith and run with the IDEA Runner - created a run configuration and chosen Scala Test)

Comment: @Belun - oh... just noticed... can you create `class` instead of `object`?

Comment: IntelliJ will swallow tests silently if they throw any exception but TestFailed. If you think tests are not recognized, run the test from shell to see the exception. Or use sbt instead of IntelliJ.

Comment: Sorry, TLAs are not googlable, right. Simple Build Tool, see http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/